# Как преобразовать данные из текстового документа в массив

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```pascal
var
  a:text;
  s:string;
  b:array of string; 
begin
  en3 := Encoding.GetEncoding(65001);
  assign(a, 'C:\Users\Новый текстовый документ.txt');
  //пусть предложение будет следующим: Найти количество согласных букв в последнем слове 
  reset(a, en3);
  while not EOF(a) do
  begin
    readln(a,s);
  end;
  print(s);
  //дальше ступор
end.
```

Comment: Так а что нужно сделать? И это паскаль или все таки делфи?

Comment: Если простыми словами,то текст вывода(Найти количество согласных букв в последнем слове) занести в массив и убрать пробелы,но в идеале просто соотнести последнее слово предложения с переменной p.s.это pascal

Comment: Я правильно понял, что нужно разбить предложение по пробелу и занести каждое слово как элемент массива? Или вам не нужны массивы, а вам нужно просто последнее слово? И последнее слово где? В каждой строке или во всем файле? А может последнее слово каждого предложения? И еще - в паскале никогда не было ни динамических массивов ни, тем более, класса TEncoding

Comment: последнее слово в данном предложении,документ состоит из одного предложения

Comment: Язык какой у вас? Не говорите, что это паскаль. Это не так

Comment: Pascal ABC.NET-приложение Pascal Program (.pas)-тип файла,смотрю в свойствах

Comment: Pascal ABC.NET - это не паскаль

Answer (score 0):

```pascal
var
  LFile: Text;
  LStr: string;
  LLastStr: string;
  LLastWord: string;
  LPos: Integer;
begin
  en3 := Encoding.GetEncoding(65001);
  Assign(LFile, 'C:\Users\Новый текстовый документ.txt');
  //пусть предложение будет следующим: Найти количество согласных букв в последнем слове 
  Reset(LFile, en3);
  LLastStr := '';  // Последняя прочитанная строка
  while not EOF(LFile) do
  begin
    Readln(LFile, LStr);
    LStr := Trim(LStr);  // Обрезаем начальные и конечные пробелы
    // Если прочитали не пустую строку, то запоминаем ее
    if LStr <> '' then
      LLastStr := LStr;
  end;
  Close(LFile);  // Не забываем закрыть файл
  // Ищем последний пробел
  LPos := LastPos(' ', LLastStr);
  // Если нашли, то копируем все до конца строки
  if LPos > 0 then
    LLastWord := Copy(LLastStr, LPos + 1, Length(LLastStr))
  else  // если пробел не нашли, то строка состоит из одного слова
    LLastWord := LLastStr;
  print(LLastWord);
end.
```